# Laravel global variable for real-time application?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, global-variables

I'm developing an application that will need to provide certain state to users in real time. Every user will use an AJAX script to 'watch' that state - every user will see all of the shared state. I'm concerned about security, since some of the shared state are secretive data.

I've tried to implement this with environment variables in `.env`, but I need arrays and I think `.env` is not compatible with arrays.

I've also tried using globals without success.

My final attempt was to use a config file and the config helper from `laravel`, but changes to the state weren't saved! I have thought about using a database table, but I don't know how to make it safe.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: The config helper doesn't save variables across different pageviews. You wouldn't want to write to `.env` either. Save it to the database (perhaps something like Redis).

Comment: Could you please give an example of what kind of information you're trying to hold in these variables, so we could give you better advice.

Comment: you can put the variables into a middleware

Comment: @MihkelAllorg The data varies, from int to strings.

Comment: @yangqi But the middleware variables aren't going to be different for each user?

Comment: it can be different depends on how you implement it. It's basically a piece of code injected into every user request.